# Using a bound property in a setter

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a button which displays three lines of text using a StackPanel and three TextBlocks.

The visibility of each textblock are using the same binding as follows:

```
<TextBlock Name="bF12Tl1" 
           Text="Line1"
           Visibility="{Binding F12ShowText}"
           HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
```

So far I have been able to use bindings in Triggers, but not in Setters.
Is it possible to use this binding to change the visibility of all three TextBlocks in a Setter like the one below?

```
<Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="4"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#737373"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray"/>
    //(Use DataBinding F12ShowText to change visibility here)
</Trigger>
```

Thank you

Comment: Are you trying to change the value of `F12ShowText` in the trigger? Or simply bind to it?

Comment: I wish to set the visibility of the TextBlock to hidden in the trigger for "IsEnabled", so yes I wish to use the binding "F12ShowText" to change the visibility (if that is possible)

Comment: What is this trigger for? is it for the button or the texblock?

Comment: The trigger is for the button itself.

Basically whenever the button is unabled I wish to set the TextBlocks to be hidden.

Comment: Why do you need to set the `IsEnabled` property to false? I mean, if you want to hide it, why not just change `Visibility` to `Hidden`? There really is no need to disable it. Or perhaps I'm missing something?

Comment: Wait a minute, is `F12ShowText` a Boolean? If so, you're better off using the `BoolToVisibilityConverter`, see [here](http://wpftutorial.net/ValueConverters.html)

Comment: Sorry, i guess i have exluded too much of my code here, but there are a bunch of other triggers that I am using for this button. If you are suggesting that i set the entire buttons visibility to hidden, then that is not what i want. I only want to set the visibility of the TextBlock to hidden.

F12ShowText is simply bound to the Visibility of the TextBlock as shown above, nothing more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was much simpler than i believed it to be, I did not need to use the DataBinding at all.

Using the Name of each TextBlock along with "TargetName" allows me to easily change the property of items not directly related to the buttons.

```
<Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="4"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#737373"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray"/>
        <Setter TargetName="bF12Tl1" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
        <Setter TargetName="bF12Tl2" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
        <Setter TargetName="bF12Tl3" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
</Trigger>
```

If anybody have an opinion if this is a good solution or not, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Something as simple as this may help

```
 <Button x:Name="MyButton"/>
    <Style  TargetType=TextBlock>
      <Style.Triggers>
         <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName= MyButton, Path=IsEnabled}" Value="false>
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden/>
         </DataTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Please note I wrote it in notepad, as I dont have VS running atm, so there maybe " or bracket missing here or there. But I don't see a reason why this would not work.